# TableViewController didSelectRowAt SIGABRT Error (no faulty connections)

Tags: swift, uitableview, realm, sigabrt

I have a TableView which gets the data from a Realm database. Now I want to select multiple rows and I want to give them a checkmark and set the "selected" attribute of the exercises to "true".
But if i try this code here I get a SIGABRT error. I've researched this error and found out that this is going to happen when I have wrong setted Outlets in the Storyboard or when I don't set the reuse identifier right. I checked this but it's all okay. Have anyone an idea where this error can come from if the storyboard is configured right? (sorry for my bad english)
Here's my code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if fromTrainingPlan == true && request2 != nil{
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        let excercises = request2![(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
        let cell: UebungenTableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! UebungenTableViewCell
        if excercises.selected == true{
            excercises.selected = false             //Crash
            print("1")
        }
        else{
            excercises.selected = true
            print("2")
        }
        if excercises.selected == true{
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
            print("3")
        }
        else{
            cell.accessoryType = .none
            print("4")
        }
    }
}
```

I used breakpoints to delimit the error and I found out that the exercise.selected = false statement causes the error, but I have no idea why..
btw: Only the first if else condition causes an error, the second doesn't crash the program.

This is the exercises class:

```
class Excercise: Object {

dynamic var trainingsplan: TrainingPlan?
dynamic var selected = false
dynamic var name = ""
dynamic var excerciseDescription = ""
dynamic var muscleGroup = ""
dynamic var record = 0
dynamic var picture: NSData?
let sets = List<TrainingSet>()
```

}

request2 has the datatype Results[Excercise]?.

Comment: Does "excercises" have an attribute of selected? and what data type are you storing in the request2 array ?

Comment: There is no need to cast IndexPath to `NSIndexPath` you can directly use it using indexPath.row

Comment: Yes, exercises has this attribute, here's the class:

Comment: See my updated question

Comment: Per https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#writes:

"All changes to an object (addition, modification and deletion) must be done within a write transaction."

Comment: Yes, that was it, now it works! Thanks!